# D3DXCreateTexture fails when running with MS "Application verifier"

Tags: c++, directx, application-verifier

Question is simple, as in title:
Why D3DXCreateTexture() sometimes fails with E_OUTOFMEMORY when running with Application Verifier? Without it - everything works fine. Well, almost, of course there's a reason I'm using App Verifier: I'm suspecting that there's a few heap corruption situations inside my code, but this error never happened running either in debug or release - only with App Verifier (then it happens in debug and in release). Dr. memory isn't too specific when it comes to it's results, and mainly points to 3rd party libraries (openssl, freefont, directx, etc), not to code I'm talking about. Do any of You have some idea, what is happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, I've found answer here on StackOverflow. Here is [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030162/debugging-an-apparent-memory-issue-in-a-c-program), and answers: one in comment by @Chad and second as qualified answer by @James McNellis. Thanks Guys!